# Time asynchronous http requests using asyncio and timeit

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures, timeit

I found this code snippet from [shipperkongen blog](http://skipperkongen.dk/2016/09/09/easy-parallel-http-requests-with-python-and-asyncio/) regarding how to send concurrent requests using asyncio. I added in timeit to calculate the time used for the requests. However, it seems to wait for all requests to complete before proceeding to calculate the time needed.

I would like to know how to get the time elapsed between the concurrent request sent and the first response. How should I modify the code to achieve this? Thanks

Note that I added in the timeit lines and I am using Python3.6

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import timeit

async def main():

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        futures = [
            loop.run_in_executor(
                executor, 
                requests.get, 
                'http://example.org/'
            )
            for i in range(20)
        ]
        for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
            stop = timeit.default_timer()
            pass
        elapsed = stop - start
        print(elapsed)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I got error that says "'return' with value in async generator" when I tried with `asyncio.as_completed(futures)`

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import timeit

async def main():

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        futures = [
            loop.run_in_executor(
                executor, 
                requests.get, 
                'http://example.org/'
            )
            for i in range(20)
        ]
        for resp in asyncio.as_completed(futures):
            res = yield resp
            print(res.status_code)
            stop = timeit.default_timer()
            elapsed = stop - start
            print(elapsed)
            return elapsed

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: `res = yield resp` should be `res = await resp`. (Note that code predating Python 3.5 used `yield from` to await - but never just `yield`.)

Comment: i am using Python 3.6 though but I will give it a try @user4815162342